# Assembly registers

Tags: windows, assembly, cpu-registers

My question WAS about getting as much info as I could about registers...No luck :/
Everyone got everything so wrong [Probably because English is not my native language].
So, the question will be more general... ;(
I need a tutorial with the BASICS!
Ah...Could I be more not-specific?
Also, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, other than a vague "Answering me with a code regarding CPU registers and writing details about it", which is far too broad in scope to be answered here. Please take a few minutes to read the [How do I ask a question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit] your question to clearly explain the problem you're having with the code you posted, and ask a **specific question** related to that code  and problem that we can answer for you.

Comment: Try you tube, it's plenty of tutorials = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gklpZIVuTBY&hd=1

Comment: What do you even mean "how to use them"? Just use their names in instructions..

Comment: @Jose Manuel Ah..I never thought of that..I only thought of printable tutorials. I am watching it..I hope it explains something about registers.

Comment: Printable? Not a good idea, paper comes from trees (I mean, real trees). Don't print, preserve nature.

Comment: You need a good tutorial with the **basics**. I suggest [Dr. Paul A. Carter's tutorial](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/). But: Don't try the examples. They are not for MASM32 on 32-bit-Windows, but for (very) different assemblers and operating systems.

Comment: @rkhb , Thanks! Could you please re-write that as an answer?

Comment: No, because ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The same applies to suggestions for a book or a tutorial without a detailed and comprehensive answer.

Comment: Well, your post did help though, thank you! @rkhb. you own the best answer for this question. Have a nice day! Laughing out loud..It seems this question will get-20 in matter of 3 days ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use any of `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi` and `edi` pretty much as you want. They can each hold any 32-bit value.

Keep in mind that if you call any Win32 API functions that they are free to modify `eax`, `ecx` and `edx`. So if you need to preserve the values of those registers across a function call you'll have to save them somewhere temporarily (e.g. on the stack).
Similarly, if you write a function that is to be called by another function (e.g. a Windows callback) you should preserve `ebx`, `esi`,`edi` and `ebp` within that function.

Some instructions are hardcoded to use certain registers. For example, the `loop` instruction uses `(e)cx`, the string instructions use `esi`/`edi`, the `div` instruction uses `eax`/`edx`, etc. You can find all such cases by going through the descriptions for all the instructions in [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Would I be wrong to assume that "high level" asm compilers adhere to the WIN32 ABI so long as you specify the conventions. i.e. unless you are doing "naked" asm, they will take care of register preservation? Anyway for benefit of OP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx

Comment: Does it make any difference if I told you I have AMD processor?

Comment: If i could use Counter, Base, Accumulator, Data registers and indexes anywhere...There would be LOTS of ways to compile a code that does the same thing..right?

Comment: @Asmuser if it's the AMD used in PCs that has the x86 architecture, then it won't make a difference at this level.

Comment: It is x64 capable...

Comment: There _are_ lots of ways to write assembly code sequences that do the same thing. Otherwise generating optimal code would be a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

The "fixed uses" of the registers derive from the ancient roots back in the 8086 days (and in some ways, even from before that).

The 8086 was an accumulator machine, you were supposed to do math mostly with `ax` (there was no `eax` yet), and a bit with `dx`. You can see this back in many instructions, for example most ALU ops have a smaller form for `op ax, imm` (also `op al, imm`) than for `op other, imm`, and the ancient decimal math instructions (`daa` and friends) operate only on `al`. There are instructions that always reference `(e)ax` and maybe `(e)dx` as "high half", see the "old multiplication" (with the single explicit operand), `imul` with an immediate was added in the 80186, `imul reg, r/m` was added in the 80386 which added a whole lot of stuff including 32bit mode. With 32bit mode also came the modern ModRM/SIB structure, here are the old [16bit](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm) version and the modern [32/64bit](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm) version. In the old version, there are only 4 registers that could ever be used in a memory operand, so there's a bit of the "fixed roles for registers" again. 32bit mode mostly removed that, except that `esp` can never be the index register (that wouldn't normally make sense anyway).

More recently, Haswell introduced `shlx` which removes the restriction that shifting by a variable amount could only be done using `cl` as the count, and `mulx` partially removed the fixed roles of registers for "wide multiplication" (80186 and 80386 only added the "general" forms for multiplication without the high half), `mulx` still gives `edx` a fixed role though.

More strangely, the relatively recently added `pblendvb` assigned a fixed role to `xmm0`, previous to that the vector registers weren't encumbered by such old-fashioned restrictions. That fixed role disappeared with AVX though, which allowed the extra operand to be encoded. `pcmpistri` and friends still assign a fixed role to `ecx` though.

With x64 came a change to 8 bit register operands, if a REX prefix is present it is now possible to use `spl`, `bpl`, `sil` and `dil`, previously unencodable, but at the cost of being able to address `ah`, `ch`, `dh` or `bh`. That's probably a symptom of moving away from special roles too, since previously it wouldn't have made much sense to be able to use `bpl`, but now that it's "more general purpose" it might have some uses (it's still often used as a base pointer though).

The general pattern is towards fewer restrictions/fixed roles. But much of the history of x86 is still visible today.

Comment: Your last sentence: for backward compatability.

Answer (score 0):

As a general comment, before you go much further, I recommend adopting a programming style, or you'll find it very hard to follow your own code. Below is a formatted example of your code, maybe not everything is correctly formatted but it gives you an idea. Once in the habit, it's easier than making higgledy-piggledy code. One of its main advantages, is with practice you can cast your eye down the code and follow it far quicker than if you have to read every line.

```
    .386
    .model flat, stdcall

    option casemap :none

    include \masm32\include\windows.inc
    include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
    include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
    includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
    includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

    .data

ProgramText db      "Hello World!", 0
BadText     db      "Error: Sum is incorrect value", 0
GoodText    db      "Excellent! Sum is 6", 0
Sum         sdword  0

    .code

start:
                            ;                         eax
    mov     ecx, 6          ; set the counter to 6    ?
    xor     eax, eax        ; set eax to              0
_label:
    add     eax, ecx        ; add the numbers         ?
    dec     ecx             ; from 0 to 6             ?
    jnz     _label          ;                         21
    mov     edx, 7          ;                         21
    mul     edx             ; multiply by 7           147
    push    eax             ; pushes eax into the stack
    pop     Sum             ; pops eax and places it in Sum
    cmp     Sum, 147        ; compares Sum to 147
    jz      _good           ; if they are equal, go to _good
_bad:
    invoke  StdOut, addr BadText
    jmp     _quit
_good:
    invoke  StdOut, addr GoodText
_quit:
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0

    end     start
```

I'll single out one line:

```
push    eax             ; pushes eax into the stack
```

Don't use comments to explain what an instruction does: use them to say what you are trying to acheive, or what the register represents, to give added value to the code.

Good luck to you: plenty of practice and midnight oil!

Comment: The OP did just copy program and comments from [Huang's tutorial](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf).

Comment: @rkhb looks like Huang can format code anyway, there are different styles ;-)

Comment: @Asmuser that's a difficult one: at what level should a tutorial explain? What knowledge should it assume so as not to get bogged down, so the reader "can't see the wood for the trees"?

Comment: Mhm...Lets get things straight..Me:AssemblyNewb=string. But I can "Hello World" if you want :)